# Is MQTT broker location influencing message delivery speed?

Tags: mqtt

Let's imagine we have device A and device B and they are communicating via MQTT. Is it faster when we are sending from A to B (A is a broker), or from A to B (B is a broker)?

We can say that device A is in a local network and device B in a cloud.

Answer (score 1):

Neither, assuming both devices are equal (same capability and load levels).

Delivery of a MQTT message from publisher to subscriber is always a 2 step process:

1. Publisher to broker
2. broker to Subscriber

The network transmit time for these 2 steps are going to be the same for both situations you described just in different orders.

Comment: But that should not be the same if publisher and broker are the same device, and subscriber is different device

Comment: Yes it will, you always have 1 leg over the network that will always be same size, so will take the same amount of time